# IE7 doesn't retain form input when back button is used?

Tags: internet-explorer, webforms

I recall IE having the ability to repopulate or maintain the form fields when the back button is used.

For example I have a form with two fields.

```
<form action="some/page" method="get">
   First Name: <input type="text" name="fName" /><br/>
   Last Name: <input type="text" name="lName" /><br/>
   <input type="Submit" />
</form>
```

The user submits the form, doesn't get the results they want, so uses the back button, but wants the input to remain.  Is this functionality that IE provides or must I write code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cache is full, going back to the page may wipe out the form data.

You can also check if the page is [using cache control](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1) to help not [clear the data on page processing](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/php-34/loss-form-data-back-button-internet-explorer-110157.html).

```
header("Cache-control: private");
```

You can try to mitigate both if the code of the page keeps things in sessions so that if the user does go back you can pre-populate with whatever they entered.